# Excel count if in sum of ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2019

I have a sheet like this:

```
  | A  | B
--+----+---
1 | 20 | 1
2 | 20 | 2
3 | 40 | 2
```

I can do `=COUNTIF(A1:A3, 40)`, but how do I count (or any other operation) on the sum of the columns? i.e. I want to do something like this: `=COUNTIF(A1:A3+B1:B3, 42)` and get 1.

I am using Excel 2019, but would like to hear answers for other spreadsheet software (especially Google sheets), too, since I may switch.

I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer: `=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A3+B1:B3=42)*1)`

See here for why: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function